# Query all data of a Google Analytcs account

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

I'm using Google Analytics API to make a Python program.

For now it's capable to make specific querys, but...

Is possible to obtain a large JSON with all the data in a Google Analytics account?

I've been searching and i didn't have found any answer.

Someone know if it's possible and how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Google Analytics api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#dimensions) lets you request data using

- A maximum of 7 dimensions in any query.
- A maximum of 10 metrics for any query.

You could request data from 2005 - Now and get all the data back for that query. However you need to remember that large amounts of data will probably return [sampled](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#samplingLevel) so the data wont be as accurate as if you returned a smaller amount of data. Even making more then one request and storing the data in a database isn't going to help you because there is no primary key to link data from one request to another.

API Limits:

There are also limits to the API as Eike stated in the comment below.   Each request returns 10000 rows of data if there is more data then you need to make another request to get the next 10000 rows.   You can make a max of 10000 requests a day against each view.  Once you have hit that max you cant make any more requests that day to that view.

Answer:  No there is no way of downloading **ALL** of your Google Analytics data.

Comment: Plus there is the general API limits (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/limits-quotas#overview) and a query returns 10 000 rows at max (as per here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#maxResults)

Comment: @EikePierstorff very good point added limits to the answer :)

Comment: Here is an [example](http://www.ryanpraski.com/python-google-analytics-api-unsampled-data-multiple-profiles/) that uses Python and the Google Analytics API and breaks up your query into 10000 row chucks and avoids sampling. You can also use the script to pull from multiple profiles.

Comment: I like the answer, but i think that you limited the answer only to the API and this case, Big Query is the option extract the unsampled data. But not All, is limited to 13 months or 10B hits. 
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3416092#pricing

Comment: you need to have a premium google analytics account to extract to big query the price of that alone i assume that most people do not have access to that.   And exporting the data to big query is diffrent then download it all into our own system.

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics stores a ton (technical term) of data; there are a lot of metrics and dimensions, and some of them (such as the users metric) have to be calculated specifically for every query. It's easy to underestimate the flexibility of Google Analytics, but the fact that it's easy to apply a carefully defined segment to three-year old data in real time means that the data will be stored in a horrendously complicated format, which is kept away from you for proprietary purposes.

So the data set would be vast, and incomprehensible. On top of that, there would be serious ramifications with regard to privacy, because of the way that Google stores the data (an issue which they can circumvent so long as you can only access the data through their protocols.

Short answer, you can take as much data as you can accurately describe and ask for, but there's no 'download all' button.